# Getting view from child-layout from tablerow (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a tablerow in a tablelayout. Now, I can get tablerows without problem. Tablerow contains a linearlayout and the linearlayout contains views that I need. Is there any possibility to get the linearlayout, and then the from it views?

I cannot do this, because View doesn't have getChildAt method:

```
View layout = row.getChildAt(j);
EditText first = (EditText)layout.getChildAt(0);
```

I cannot do this either, because it leads to runtime error when converting View to Layout:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)row.getChildAt(j);
EditText first = (EditText)layout.getChildAt(0);
```

Comment: please post XML Layout and Logcat , plus what j means?

Answer (score 0):

If someone has better solution then post it and I'll mark it as solution.

The way I solved this was by adding ID to layout before adding it to the tablerow:

```
layout.setId(id);
row.addView(layout);
```

And then getting layout by ID:

```
View layout =row.getChildAt(j);
LinearLayout layoutLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(layout.getId());
EditText first = (EditText)layout1.getChildAt(0);
```

I couldn't post XML-file because layout is made programmatically.